# TypeError in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to pull specific values from a dictionary but my program keeps throwing a TypeError on some values from the dictionary. Can someone tell me why?

**python program**

```
import csv,os,re,sys

input_dict = csv.DictReader(open("./MCPlayerData/AllPlayerData2.csv"))     
def list_scale_values(regexmatch,stopOnNA,person):
    data=[]
    for key in person:
        if re.match(regexmatch, key):
            try:
                data.append(int(person[key]))
            except (ValueError):
                data.append('NA') 
                if(stopOnNA):
                    data=['NA'] #if any NA return NA    
                    break
    return data

try:
    for person in input_dict:
        print(list_scale_values(r'npi[0-9]+',True,person))  
except (TypeError):
    type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print(type)
    print(value)
    print(traceback)
    print '\n---\n',person,'\n---'
    sys.exit()

print('DONE')
```

**error output**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "correlations.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(list_scale_values(r'npi[0-9]+',True,person))  
  File "correlations.py", line 9, in list_scale_values
    if re.match(regexmatch, key):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Could you take the problematic code out of the `try` block and give us the text of the traceback?

Comment: I would be happy to, Is this what I should run? `traceback.print_exc()`

Comment: Just comment out `try:`, unindent the `for` statement and the `print()` function by one level each, and comment out the entire `except` block. This will print the traceback to the console in the normal way.

Comment: Could you print out `type(key)` please? inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, After doing what you suggested I got a lot of `type 'str'` then on the error line I got `type 'NoneType'`

Comment: Your csv file is probably missing a header column, which causes a NoneType key for a dictionary add this `if key != None and re.match(regexmatch, key):`
instead of ``if re.match(regexmatch, key):`

Comment: That would make sense if this happened on the person, but this is happening half-way down the list of people. Could I still be having that problem if some people worked before?

Comment: @Rilcon42  it is possible if your csv file is written badly where one row somehow skipped a column to write. So the best solution would be to check if key is not None

Comment: At the beginning of the `for key in person:` loop add this line: `if not isinstance(key, str): print('error: key of type {} encountered'.format(type(key)))`. If it prints anything your csv file is corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem check if the key is a valid string or buffer before a regular expression is made.

so instead of `if re.match(regexmatch, key):`

write the following code

```
if key != None and re.match(regexmatch, key):
```

**To answer the question why it would happen for some `person` in the csv dictionary?**

If the csv file does not take into consideration for all the columns in a row for each row this situation is totally possible for only certain rows, in this case `people`

To give an example :

consider the following CSV file

```
name,type,address,value
zoo,1,111,2
foo,2,222,,
bar,3,333,5
```

This would get the following results  for the persons in `csv.DictReader(open("filename.csv"))`

```
 {'type': '1', 'name': 'abc', 'value': '2', 'address': '111'}
 {None: [''], 'type': '2', 'name': 'foo', 'value': '', 'address': '222'}
 {'type': '3', 'name': 'bar', 'value': '5', 'address': '333'}
```

So in this case it would work for `people[0]` and `people[2]` but fail at `people[1]`